# Acces Denied - Generating a directory in Microsoft Server with Silverlight

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight

I have searched the internet and cannot seem to find the answer to my question. I have also searched thoroughly through stackoverflow, which might help me to pose a better question.

I have made an application with webservices in C#, which is running in Silverlight. 
My problem is that the application has to create a directory with a relative path. Locally it works, but when I upload it to Microsoft Server it does not create a directory.

It says the following: 
*File operation not permitted. Acces to path: 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/...' is denied.*

I use this line of code for the creation:
*Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("TEMP/");*

On the map where the application is running, I have granted all rights to public and IIS user. But it still gives the same error. Besides this, I have also wrote a small piece of independent code in .Net to create a directory. This was to test the access and that works.

So I don't really know where to look.

---

### @Update - 22/05/2014 - 14:29

I have literally deleted all code and just kept a create directory function with one button and one event handler:
*Directory.CreateDirectory("path");*

I have noticed that relative path's do not work in Silverlight here. (He seems to think the path the browser(i.e. Chrome) as being the parent and not the application's path).

Some other findings are, that if I put in the absolute path. Locally it works, but when i upload it to the server it again says acces denied...

Any tips are very welcome!

Comment: the second application you have created for testing allow you to create a directory on same path c:/inetpub/wwwroot/.? or you have created on some different path

Comment: On the same path. With the application I have tried the following things: Locally with an absolute path, on the server with an absolute path and on the server with a relative path.

Comment: Try this one Directory.CreateDirectory( Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TEMP"));

Comment: I have tried it. Again locally it works, but not on the server! (Nice to see another method and getting a similar result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem!

The following was going wrong:
My silverlight application consists of two parts. A Web-service and a Client;

- The Web-service executes as being the user: IUSR, which had the full rights on the server.
- The Client executes as being the user: DefaultAppPool.

The problem with this, is that the DefaultAppPool user can not be given rights as easily. If you try to give rights the default way, in the map settings, the DefaultAppPool user cannot be found.

The correct way to give full rights to DefaultAppPool, is to go to the command console and type:

*icacls c:\"Path to the map" /grant “IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool”:(F)*

For more detailed information about this, check the following link:
http://eufuckingreka.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/granting-defaultapppool-permissions-to-a-direction-on-windows-server-2008/